# Trying to read a parquet file and write the data to a csv file in aws s3 using glue with pyspark

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

New to pyspark. Trying to read a parquet file and write the data to a csv file in aws s3 using glue with pyspark

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext


sc= SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext=GlueContext(sc)
spark= glueContext.spark_session

dynamicFramne=glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        connection_type="s3",
        connection_options={"paths": {"s3://path/abc.parquet/"]},
        format= "parquet"
        )
        
        
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        connection_type="s3",
        connection_options={"paths": {"s3://path/abc"]},
        format= "csv",
        format_options= {
        "separator":",",
        },
        )
```

Comment: Where is the question? What is the issue? What have you tried?

Comment: Is it a solution or a Question? Please eloborate.

Comment: I tried to read a parquet file in aws s3 using glue pyspark dynamic data frame and tried to write it to csv file in s3. But nothing is working. How can I read a  parquet file in aws s3 using glue pyspark dynamic data frame and to write it to csv file in s3?